# How to make a open file dialog in a metro style app xaml 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

How do i make a open file dialog in xaml 2012 as i am new to metro style. I know c# 2010 there there is an option of open file dialog here there is no option so how can i make a open file dialog can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

In a metro style app (WinRT), you would use the [FileOpenPicker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR207847) for this purpose.  Here's an example:

```
            var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
            filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            filePicker.SettingsIdentifier = "PicturePicker";
            filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Select Files";

            var selectedFiles = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
            if (selectedFiles != null)
            {
                // do something with the selected files
            }
```

There's an example project that demonstrates it [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-app-extension-0cb95155).